# NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient , throws error even in http client is injected

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-coverage

```
 import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
        import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
        import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
        import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
        import { DrawerService} from '../services/create-work-order-confirmation-drawer.service';
        import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
        import { ConfirmationDrawerComponent } from './create-work-order-confirmation-drawer.component';
        import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        
        describe('ConfirmationDrawerComponent ', () => {
          let component: ConfirmationDrawerComponent ;
          let fixture: ComponentFixture<ConfirmationDrawerComponent >;
          let CreateServices = DrawerService;
        
          beforeEach(async (() => {
             TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [ ConfirmationDrawerComponent ],
              imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule,RouterModule.forRoot([])],
              providers: [{
                provide: DrawerService
              }],
              schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
            })
            .compileComponents();
          }));
        
          beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfirmationDrawerComponent );
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            CreateServices = TestBed.get(DrawerService);
            fixture.detectChanges();
          });
        
          it('should create', () => {
            expect(component).toBeTruthy();
          });
        });
```

Not sure whats the issue!
what have I missed?
I have added all the modules to the imports, have I missed something?[image]
***imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule,RouterModule.forRoot([])],***

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace of the error

Comment: i have added the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is coming from the spec file of `CreateWorkOrderConfirmationDrawerService`, go to that file and check if `HttpClientTestingModule` is imported